# How to customize hover information in ggplotly object?

Tags: r, plotly

Is there a way to customize hoverinfo in a ggplotly object?

For example,

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y= am, color = as.factor(cyl)))+geom_point()

ggplotly(p)
```

The hover information box here contains three variables:disp,am and factor(cyl). How to include more variables or exclude existing variables in the hover information box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can include required variables in `aes()` then use `tooltip` to specify which should be displayed:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y= am, color = as.factor(cyl), 
                        gear=gear, hp=hp))+geom_point()
ggplotly(p,tooltip = c("x", "gear", "hp"))
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

A cleaner way is to just add everything within the `ggplot` environment, using aesthetics two times, in order to pass just the full, single object onto `ggplotly()`:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(label = gear, label2 = hp)) + 
     geom_point(aes(x = disp, y= am, color = as.factor(cyl)))

ggplotly(p)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to add html formatting to your hover information you can set the `text` attribute using `paste()` in the `aes()` funtction. Then you use the `text` value from the `aes()` in `tooltip` argument in `ggplotly()`:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y= am, color = as.factor(cyl), 
                        text= paste("Displacment: ", disp, "<br>", 
                                    "Automatic: ", am, "<br>",
                                    "Number of cylinders: ", cyl, "<br>",
                                    "mpg: ", mpg, sep = "")))+
  geom_point()

ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text"))
```

This approach allows you to include variables, which are not included in the standard `aes()` arguments, to the hover info (like `mpg` in the above code chunk).