# how change hover text in plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this piece of code.
How can I please easy  change hover text `diff` to `newlabel` ?
Here is my site http://webcovid19.online/

```
 ggplotly(
        ggplot(my_data, aes(x=date, y=diff)) + 
        geom_bar(stat='identity',fill='red')  +
        scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) 
    )
```

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598011/how-to-customize-hover-information-in-ggplotly-object/40598524

Comment: yes, I was checking this post already before, but from there is not very clear for me how to do it in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the text in the tooltip adding `text` to your `aes()` in `ggplot`. Here, you can include both `date` and `diff` with whatever text label you want (or just include `diff` alone). Within `ggplotly`, you can include `tooltip = "text"` to refer to this text with hover.

```
library(plotly)
library(scales)

ggplotly(
  ggplot(my_data, aes(x=date, y=diff, text = paste("Date:", date, "\nnewlabel:", diff))) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity', fill='red')  +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = comma),
  tooltip = "text"
)
```

Comment: muchas gracias Ben

Comment: Hi Ben, Is it possible to change text size of hover text ?
I found something here via hoverlabel , but not sure how to do it in my case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076722/change-size-of-hover-text-in-plotly

Comment: Hi Andrew - if you save your `ggplotly()` object as `gg`, then you can change the `style` such as: `style(gg, hoverlabel = list(font = list(size = 24)))`...it is tricky with all the lists involved in this, but it is more clearly described [here](https://plotly-r.com/controlling-tooltips.html).

Comment: Excellent !  I use this way ...`%>%
      style (hoverlabel = list(font=list(size=20)))`